# best approach for roll back in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, rollback

I have a web application built using struts2 + hibernate. There are several Entity bean class's which represents the database tables for my project. I have a situation where one record is dependent on another record like below code:

```
  Dao.getIncomeInstance.save(User user,Income income);
  Dao.getBudgetInstance.update(Budget budget,Income income);
```

each method has `session.getTransaction().commit();` that means I am committing the transaction. But irrespective of the error in Budget the Income record is getting saved which I am assuming is not a right approach. I have an approach in mind which is creating a new method which accepts another parameter of Transaction object to the Budget method like this  `Dao.getBudgetInstance.update(Transaction trans,Budget budget,Income income);` so that If there are any issues/error I can roll back , But don't like it as I will end up creating multiple methods with the same name( around 10+ methods with the same name as **update** which accepts different parameters).

I am new to hibernate. Can some one suggest me of an approach by which I can create a rollback point and do all my operations and can do rollback when ever I want (some thing like below. These are just assumptions to pinpoint my idea):

```
  Rollback roll=null;
  try{
  roll=session.transaction.createRollBack();
  Dao.getIncomeInstance.save(User user,Income income);
  Dao.getBudgetInstance.update(Budget budget,Income income);
  }
  catch(RuntimeException exe)
  {
   // do the rollback with roll reference
  }
```

Any suggestion about the better approach is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Transactions should not be demarcated in DAO methods, but in the business service method that calls all DAOs, so a single transaction encompasses all related changes to the database, so that all or none of them are committed.

In modern enterprise code, transactions are usually demarcated declaratively by whatever dependency injection container you happen to use (Spring, CDI, EJB, ...). With Spring, for instance, one simply annotates the business service to make it transactional:

```
@Transactional
public void whatever(User user, Budget budget, Income income) {
    incomeDao.save(user, income);
    budgetDao.update(budget, income);
}
```

Further reading: [Spring reference manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#transaction)

Comment: yes I understand. But Since I am using struts2 in my project I can not change all my code and project to adopt the spring framework now. Can you suggest any thing that can be done in struts2 or hibernate standpoint.?